# Available RTC modules

Tags: i2c, rtc

I know the procedure to enable an external RTC, but I just wonder which are the available supported chip (in config.txt and to use with modprobe).

Where can I find such a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read `/boot/overlays/README` particularly the  `i2c-rtc` section.

**DO NOT** use `modprobe` use Device Tree!

Pick any of the listed modules.

I recommend `ds3231` which is a good performer and works from 3.3V, although many of the others work well.

Comment: I also recommend DS3231, it (almost) never misses a beat. The DS1307 has been known to drift many minutes, even hours, every month.