# i2c Real Time Clock IC on Raspberry

Tags: i2c, rtc, device-tree

I am using an industrial device based on a Compute Module Raspberry Pi 3 called  [Kunbus RevPi Core 3+](https://revolutionpi.com/revpi-core/).

The device is shipped with Raspbian and a pre compiled Image but I would like to install an Ubuntu Server 22.04 distro (much better for my pourpose). The Ubuntu started without a problem but I can't see the Real Time Clock.

Here is the wiring of the IC for providing the RTC and an another i2c IC.

[image]

The Kunbus guys mantain a Kernel patched with the Kernel Tree Overlay for the Hardware they have attacched to the board: [revpi-core-overlay.dts](https://github.com/RevolutionPi/linux/blob/96fdda2f0d71e10f7e5c67aef155cf73a07d0e50/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/revpi-core-overlay.dts)

In the Overlay there's the specification of the RTC IC:

```json
fragment@3 {
        target = <&i2c1>;
        __overlay__ {
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&i2c1_pins>;
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            status = "okay";

            rtc@51 {
                compatible = "nxp,pcf2129";
                reg = <0x51>;
                status = "okay";
            };

            crypto@60 {
                compatible = "atmel,atecc508a";
                reg = <0x60>;
                status = "okay";
            };
        };
    };
```

So, if I have understood here the IC nxp,pcf2129 is on the line 1 with an address `0x51`

### First try, load the module manually

With the info I found the the Overlay and in the datasheet I tried to load the kernel module manually.

I found the driver in the kernel tree [rtc-pcf2127](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/rtc/rtc-pcf2127.c) and I have loaded the module:

```bash
sudo modprobe rtc-pcf2127
```

The modules was loaded:

```bash
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsmod | grep rtc
rtc_pcf2127            24576  0
```

According to the documentation I found here: [instantiating-devices](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/i2c/instantiating-devices.html) I have tried to assign the driver an address:

```bash
echo pcf2129 0x51 /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
```

But no `/dev/rtc` has appeared:

```bash
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ls -al /dev/rtc
ls: cannot access '/dev/rtc': No such file or directory
```

scanning the i2c bus has no answere too:

```bash
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

How could properly use the rtc device?

Thanks,

S.

Comment: You should try compiling the dts file to a dtb (using `dtc`, the device tree compiler), then you can include it via `/boot/config.txt`.

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't compile because at the start of the file there are 2 include: `#include <dt-bindings/gpio/gpio.h>
#include <dt-bindings/pinctrl/bcm2835.h>` and I don't know where to find them.

Comment: https://github.com/RevolutionPi/linux/tree/96fdda2f0d71e10f7e5c67aef155cf73a07d0e50/include/dt-bindings

Comment: Yes, that's the GitHub of the kernel they use but I have the Ubuntu kernel, I would like just to let the RTC to Work, not all the other fancy hardware stuff.

Comment: Ahhhh no, I got the point... you mean that the two includes stay there! mmmmm, I'll try

Comment: No, unfortunately I wasn't able to build the dtc. 
`root@ubuntu:~/linux# dtc -o dtb -o revpi-core-overlay.dtbo -@ ./arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/revpi-core-overlay.dts
Error: ./arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/revpi-core-overlay.dts:9.1-9 syntax error
FATAL ERROR: Unable to parse input tree`

Comment: I know very little about it, TBH.  If you want to pursue that, I notice there are some linux oriented tutorials around, then if you have a specific problem you should ask on SO proper, there's a `device-tree` tag there with ~500 questions, nearly 10x what's here -- and dt in general seems intended to not be platform specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution!!!!

No building custom modules is needed, only stock kernel configuration.
The trick is that the I2c used bus **IS NOT THE STANDARD ONE** (i.e. usually with Raspberry the I2c bus is on GPIO 2 and GPIO 3, which on Kunbus are used for other pourpose).
The GPIO where the RTC is attached are the GPIO 44 and GPIO 45, you could check on the provided schematic and you could even see that there are the two pull up resistors needed by the bus to properly work.

That was the difficult thing to spot, as soon as I have understood that I have decided to configure a second I2c bus and let the RTC driver use that.

1. Configure the Tree Overlay

I have added these two lines to

```bash
/boot/firmware/config.txt
```

Code:

```bash
dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,i2c_gpio_sda=44,i2c_gpio_scl=45,bus=2
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,pcf2129
```

The first line configure the second I2c bus and assign the correct 2 GPIO, the second line ask to the kernel to use the driver for the pcf2129 for RTC.

- Create a Service for Systemd

In the service you have to create a new device when the system start up:

```bash
[Unit]
Description=RTC configuration for pcf2129

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/configrtc.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the script used in the service:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo pca2129 0x51 > /sys/class/i2c-dev/i2c-2/device/new_device
sleep 0.5
hwclock -s || hwclock -w
```

In this way I have the RTC device working at startup every time with my Ubuntu Server 22.04.

```
root@kunbus02:~# i2cdetect -y 2
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- 51 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: 60 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Hope that this little tutorial could be of some help to some other users.

Regards,

Stefano

Answer (score 0):

Fiddling with modprobe is ancient history (as are customised kernels).

All modern Linux use Device Tree to configure hardware.
There a `i2c-rtc` overlay which adds support for a number of I2C Real Time Clock devices.

All you need to do is include `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,pcf2129` in `config.txt`.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/72974/8697 and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100127/8697

Comment: I have tried with `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,pcf2129` and with `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,pcf2127` but no success. The `/dev/rtc` is not there and `i2cdetect` is still empty :-(
Reading syslog I found an error: `Mar  8 08:48:16 ubuntu kernel: [    2.807099] rtc-pcf2127-i2c: probe of 1-0051 failed with error -121` What does it mean? Wrong address?